# Помогите с тестом)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Однажды ведущий на свадьбе решил развлечь гостей, пока они собираются, и установил правило: как только приходит новый гость, все выпивают за здоровье молодых.

Давай поможем ведущему посчитать, сколько порций выпивки нужно приготовить, и напишем функцию get_drinks. Она принимает целое число number_of_guests и возвращает необходимое количество порций выпивки, чтобы хватило всем гостям.

Например, если number_of_guests = 3, то понадобится:

1 порция, когда придёт первый гость;
ещё 2 порции, когда придёт второй;
и ещё 3, когда придёт третий.
Итого 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 порций.

Предлагаем воспользоваться циклом for и, когда приходит следующий гость, просто добавлять то, что выпили сейчас, к тому, что выпили раньше.
вот пример моего решения

```
def get_drinks(number_of_guests: int) -> int:
    # write your code here
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, number_of_guests):
        sum += i
        print(sum)
```

но выводит результат null
в чем ошибка у меня?

Comment: @ДмитрийБалух сдвигаете `print` на уровень `for`, меняете его на `return sum`, вызываете `print(get_drinks(5))`, получаете 10

Comment: спасибо) пропустило дальше)

Comment: Не называйте переменные функциями!!! Сколько раз говорить!!!

Answer (score 2):

Задача решается аналитически, и, кажется, маленький Гаусс решил её во втором классе, написав формулу `n*(n+1)/2`.

Ошибка в том, что, хотя Вы написали функцию, которая посчитает то же самое через цикл, но функцию Вы нигде не вызываете ни с каким параметром.

Comment: Задача модуля по циклам, и по этому надо написать код по этой теме

Comment: Зачем удалил ответ?

Comment: @Qwertiy - мне показалось, что я ответил недостаточно доброжелательно. К тому же, возможно, нужен более подробный ответ. Тогда - поа оставлю,а может, кто то лучше напишет

Comment: Ну вроде фраза про то, что функцию надо вызвать - это и есть ответ. Ну и формула тоже полезная.

Comment: тест сам ее вызывает, главное что бы ошибок не было. А у меня почему то print выдает результат null

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_drinks(number_of_guests: int) -> int:
    sum = 0
    for drinks in range(0, number_of_guests + 1):
        sum += drinks
    return sum
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Как вы думаете, стоит ли давать переменным имена встроенных функций?

Comment: не стоит, конечно)